# How to open or access data from an Android Fragment from Xamarin Forms code?

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an Android fragment that has a function that outputs a hexadecimal string. I need some way of either opening this fragment from Xamarin Forms code, or sending the string to my Xamarin Forms page.

I have tried to implement a MessagingCenter script that would send the string to my Xamarin Forms code, but my issue is that I cannot figure out how to create an intent from Forms that would start the Android Fragment. What I need is for some way that when a button is pressed in forms, it would either call the Fragment or open an android page with the fragment.

Xamarin Forms:

```
private void OnGenerate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(App.Current, "OpenPage", (snd, arg) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            tagLabel.Text = arg;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: if you want to call some Android specific code from Forms, use DependencyService.  Is there a reason that it specifically has to be a fragment, or could you move the code into its own class?

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at implementing that. I think I should be able to move the code into its own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just use the [Preferences API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)? You just add the nuget package to your Core and Android projects.

Then in your Android project, you store the value

`Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");`

and in your Core project, you can just get that value using

`var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");`

Comment: Thank you, I think that could work for me. Do you know how I could call the Android function though from the Xamarin Forms code? For instance, when a button is pressed on the Forms page, I would need it to run the Android portion.

Comment: If you want to run an Android function on a button press, the easiest way could be by creating a custom button using a renderer: https://www.wintellect.com/supercharging-xamarin-forms-with-custom-renderers-part-1/ (Or else just create a custom page renderer)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out.

Comment: Any success @zack

Comment: I am trying to go the route of doing the custom page renderer, but am having an issue with setting the current activity. It's value is null even though I've tried setting it a few different ways. I've even tried using the cross current activity plugin from James Montemagno but nothing has worked so far. It's strange because I am able to get it to work using the xamarin forms custom renderer sample, and the code is the same as far as I can tell. @Saamer

Comment: Here is my code for reference. My issue is that it throws an exception on the line that defines the view, because the activity is null. 

```activity = this.Context as Activity;
    view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Test_Layout this, false);


     textureView = view.FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.textureView);
     textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;```

Comment: Can you share a link to your code on Github so i can clone it? Or create a minimal sample project that has just what you're trying to do? Your error could in something as little as the attributes

Comment: Yes, sorry, it did turn out to be something simple. The issue turned out to be that I wasn't specifying the activity to be an Android.App.Activity when tryinng to get the context of it. The custom renderer is now working as intended. Thank you so much for all your help!